# How can you put two arrays in the same order?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pulling two arrays from my database. One of them is from the `friends` table, and the other is from the `members` table.

What I'm trying to do is display the usernames of the friends on the profile. That's done, but now I'm trying to make links to the person who has that username's profile (click on userName to go to userName's profile). The friends array ($friendsarr) has all of the ID's of the friends, and the username array ($friendunamearr) has the usernames that match the ID's. However, they are not in the same order.

If I forgot to mention earlier, the members table has an ID field. That's how I'm pulling all of the usernames.

For example, let's say there's user1 and user2. User1's ID is 1. User2's ID is 2. When I click on the link to User1's profile, it takes me to User2's profile, and vice versa.

Is there a way to put them in the same order?

Comment: Where are your queries?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense - it sounds like the problem is just that you are printing the wrong data, or selecting the wrong data - not that there's anything to do with ordering arrays. Post your code. - If you change your friendsArr to be an array where the id is the key and the username is the value, the problem would be solved.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. This is the code http://pastebin.com/gaXaCCM4 for the friends area <?php block.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about SQL joins.

Comment: Yes, you definitely need joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two tables before you even put them in an array. Then the data is already matched up for you.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I'll definitely check this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick play you can do it with something like the following (not tested)

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$sql = mysql_query("
SELECT members.username, Sub1.FreindIds
FROM members
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id AS FreindIds FROM friends WHERE friend_id=$usrid
    UNION
    SELECT friend_id AS FreindIds FROM friends WHERE user_id=$usrid
) Sub1
ON members.id = Sub1.FreindIds");

$checksql = mysql_num_rows($sql);

while ($row_comp = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
{
    echo '<a href="../../member/profile?id=' . $row_comp['FreindIds'] . '">' . $row_comp['username'] . '</a><br />';
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);

?>
```